# Error al decodificar datos con fichero de Seguridad

Tags: c#, saml, single-sign-on

Tengo que implementar un SSO, con un sistema Okta, y me envía el XML encriptado con un certificado de seguridad, que me han facilitado.

El certificado lo consigo leer bien, pero viene sin clave privada, por lo que al usar la clave publica y al tratar de desencriptar recibo el siguiente error

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'La clave no existe.

Para cargar el certificado uso el siguiente código

```
 var ss = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (var keyChar in ClavePrivada.ToCharArray())
            ss.AppendChar(keyChar);

        X509Certificate2 cerDecrypt = new X509Certificate2(certificateFile, ss);

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cerDecrypt.PublicKey.Key;
        
        var fooByte = rsa.Decrypt(data,false);
```

Los certficados y el metadata necesarios, los tengo en una carpeta del proyecto.

Alguien me puede ayudar

***** EDITADO ****************

Os comparto la información que se lee del certificado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También os pongo la llama completa de como cargo del certificado y como leo el dato del XML, que necesito decodificar.

```
XmlNodeList elemData = response.GetElementsByTagName("xenc:CipherValue");
        RutaCertificado = Server.MapPath(RutaFicheros + "okta.cert");
        for (int i = 1; i < elemData.Count; i++)
        {
            Data = elemData[i].InnerXml;               

            byte[] SamlByte = Convert.FromBase64String(Data);

            X509Certificate2 cerDecrypt = new X509Certificate2(RutaCertificado);

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cerDecrypt.PublicKey.Key;

            var fooByte = rsa.Decrypt(SamlByte, false);

            //var mail = X509Decrypt(SamlByte, RutaCertificado, privateKeyText);
        }
```

Este es el XML que recibo

```
 <saml2p:Response Destination="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/BackOffice/Validate"
             ID="id73607904232296671938710433"
             IssueInstant="2021-06-25T06:01:02.988Z"
             Version="2.0"
             xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
             >
<saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
              xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
              >http://www.okta.com/ex..................</saml2:Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
        <ds:Reference URI="#id73607904232296671938710433">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>LM4QiOAUqynTr2eF3fxHPEUpMfjlNaBbvKBkHVJvlSg=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>H7sX3pAKDBETEtmcgNuHa90lrkU1+...........................
    </ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDljCCAn6gAwIBAgIGAV1VxVpAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGLMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEG
            ..........................................
            </ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<saml2p:Status xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
</saml2p:Status>
<saml2:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <xenc:EncryptedData Id="_d94b006db4db53071df05233193f954b"
                        Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
                        xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                        >
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"
                               xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                               />
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:RetrievalMethod Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#EncryptedKey"
                                URI="#_9ef4959105c46c31fff0eda0055c2830"
                                />
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <xenc:CipherValue>jWxhen+PSeeSohWQ/XJARF5vjuN4a+.......................</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
    <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="_9ef4959105c46c31fff0eda0055c2830"
                       xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                       >
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"
                               xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                               >
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"
                             xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                             />
        </xenc:EncryptionMethod>
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDLDCCApWgAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQ0FADCBsjELMAkGA1UEBhMCZXMxETAPBgNVBA.......
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <xenc:CipherValue>G4EAS......</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
        <xenc:ReferenceList>
            <xenc:DataReference URI="#_d94b006db4db53071df05233193f954b" />
        </xenc:ReferenceList>
    </xenc:EncryptedKey>
</saml2:EncryptedAssertion>
```

</saml2p:Response>

Comment: el xml lo tenemos plis?

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, para añadir el XML que recibo

Comment: es una chorada, y seguro que no es, pero yo en otros temas que tengo muy parecidos no uso ```var``` en vez de ```byte``` en la conversion del string a byte

Comment: te fijaste en la doc de microsoft? ahi esta todo como hacerlo y veo que te faltan lineas. me queda poco tiempo para responder y no lo tengo en este momento a esta hora. mañana mas descansado lo miro de nuevo y te paso la respuesta aunque no puedo probarla.

Answer (score 1):

Lo siento, no tengo reputación para comentar, así que comparto como respuesta mi reflexión.

Si no me equivoco, tienes que usar la clave pública del certificado que te han enviado para desencriptar el XML, ya que lo normal es que el servidor lo encripte con su clave privada y tu lo desencriptes con su clave pública para validar la autoría de lo que te llega, así que lo que haces parece correcto.

Sin embargo, estás cargando el archivo del certificado con un password, lo que es necesario sólo para cargar la clave privada. La prueba más fácil que puedes hacer es quitar el "ss" del "new X509..."

Otro posible problema es que estés cargando el certificado del store equivocado o que el usuario de la aplicación no tenga permiso para acceder a éste, pero mencionas que tienes los archivos en una carpeta así que no creo que ese sea el problema.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
X509Certificate2 cerDecrypt = new X509Certificate2(certificateFile);

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cerDecrypt.PublicKey.Key;
    
    var fooByte = rsa.Decrypt(data,false);
```

Si puedes compartir la manera de cargar el certificado igual vemos algo más.

Comment: gracias por contribuir, no soy experto en C# pero entendí por que se produce el error, te invito a que complementes tu respuesta con un ejemplo :D

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero lamentablemente sigue saliendo el mismo error. He añadido la parte completa del código, desde que leo el dato del XML, hasta que lo intento descifrar

Comment: ¿Podrías probar con `var fooByte = rsa.Decrypt(data,**true**);` a ver si es tema de padding? (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.decrypt)

Comment: Nada eso me da error de que no puede con los espacios en blanco

Comment: Lo siento mucho, se me acabaron las ideas :(